# Typescript React issue with assigning first item from first object

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following code:

```
this.setState({ rooms, room_id: rooms.length > 0 ? rooms?[0].room_id : '' })
```

I am getting an error at rooms?[0].room_id (room_id) being the trouble here.

I have declared my props (out of desperations as any) as follows:

```
room: {rooms: any}
```

The error states:

```
any
Property 'room_id' does not exist on type 'number[]'.ts(2339)
```

I am unable to resolve this. Why does typescript think it is 'number' if I declared the whole object as type any? I am hoping TS got confused and the actual error is somewhere else but for that, I need someone who already understand where might be a problem. Thank you for all your kind help and comments.

Comment: Please show your `useState` and the full code where the variable `rooms` comes from.

Comment: This definition doesn't quite make sense. You're saying that you have an *object* that has a property called `rooms`, which is `any`. However, in that `setState` call, you're directly referencing some variable called `rooms`, which doesn't seem to be a nested value of some object (unless maybe you destructured it beforehand). Show the full code

Comment: `rooms?[0]` Did you mean `rooms?.[0]`? The `.` is necessary when doing optional chaining. Or since you already checked if length is greater than zero, maybe you meant `rooms[0]`